# Please explain this batch file command to unzip files

Tags: batch-file, runtime-error, 7zip

```
for /r %%I IN (' *.zip ') DO (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpnI" "%%I"
)
pause
```

Hi, I got this batch command online that unzips files recursively.
I would like to understand what the For loop does in this case.

I'm asking this question because I receive errors when running the bat file because the command also picks folders and files of other extensions apart froma *.zip and throws the following error.

```
D:\Unzip_folders\New folder>("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"D:\Unzip_folders\New folder\23Nov2015\error_log.17112015\'" "D:\Unzip_folders\New folder\23Nov2015\error_log.17112015\'" )

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
D:\Unzip_folders\New folder\23Nov2015\error_log.17112015\'
```

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run there `for /?` and read the output help for this command explaining `%~dpnI` (drive letter, path and name without extension of found file) and `%I` (name of found file with extension. 7-Zip has a help explaining command `x` (extract) and switch `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

if you analyze the error message, you notice a single `'` at the end of each filename. That's because you use the wrong sort of quotes.

Skip them entirely:

```
for /r %%I IN (*.zip) DO (
```

or use doublequotes:

```
for /r %%I IN ("*.zip") DO (
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Kept looking for help and my code works nw.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r %%I IN (*.zip) DO (
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpnI" "%%I"
)
pause
```

Your code is incorrect. This is the proper one.